# Limits of a complex function $F(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\gamma\}$ as $z \rightarrow p\in \gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let $\gamma$ parameterize the complex unit circle. We have the following holomorphic function $F$ on  $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\gamma\}$:
$$F(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{\zeta}\frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$$

We are supposed to find all points $p \in \partial D_1(0)$ (all p in the complex unit circle) such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow p, |z|<1} F(z) = \frac{1}{p}$ **or** $\lim_{z\rightarrow p, |z|>1} F(z) = \frac{1}{p}$

I did the following for $0<|z|<1$ , using Cauchy's Integral Formula:
$$F(z)
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{\zeta}\frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f(\zeta)\frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta
=f(z)
=\frac{1}{z}
$$

Which would mean $z\rightarrow p\implies F(z)\rightarrow p$

So all the points $p$ we are looking for would be all points on the complex unit circle.
This seems so simple I'm afraid I missed something. Also we never needed the second condition from the **or** statement.

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula is not applicable to  your function  since  it is not analytic in the unit disk.

Comment: $F$ is in fact analytic in the unit disk and $F(0)=0$. So it is certainly false that $F(z)=\frac 1  z$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Got it, can you please give me a hint as to how to solve this?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Does it have to be analytic on the unit disk? In our definition of Cauchy's Integral Formula we only need a domain $G\in \mathbb{C}$, sow we could just exclude $0$? $f$ is analytic everywhere else....

Comment: You cannot aplly Cauchy's Theorem and Cauchy's integral formula to aribitrary regions. They are valid only for simply connected regions.

Answer (score 1):

For $|z|<1,$

$$F(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta^2(1-z\zeta^{-1})}\,d\zeta$$ $$ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\zeta^{-2}\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z\zeta^{-1})^n\right)\,d\zeta = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_\gamma z^n\zeta^{-2-n}\,d\zeta =0.$$

Using a similar procedure, if $|z|>1,$ we find we find $F(z)=-1/z.$

The answer to the question thus seems to be that for no $p$ on the unit circle do we get the limit $1/p.$